# Using Reflection: java.reflection.Constructor.newInstance()

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to instantiate a class using the Constructor.newInstance() method but am running into trouble properly providing the parameters for the constructor. The problem is, the constructor parameters are made available as a String[] array, the elements of which I have to cast to their corresponding types. This works for objects, but what if some of the parameters are primitive types?

Here's a simplified example (that seems to work fine until I hit a primitive type):

```
Class fooClass = Class.forName("Foo");
Constructor[] fooCtrs = fooClass.getConstructors();
Class[] types = fooCtrs[0].getParameterTypes();
Object[] params = new Object[types.length];

for(int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
    params[i] = types[i].cast(args[i]);  // Assume args is of type String[]
}
```

Once I hit an int or something, I'll get a ClassCastException.
Am I doing anything wrong? Do I need to manually wrap any primitives I encounter, or is there a built in way of doing that?

Comment: Are you saying args is a String[]? what are some example classnames in the types[]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct, you need to add primitives in a wrapper.

Read about primitives in [Constructor.newInstance()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) docs

*Parameters:
    initargs - array of objects to be passed as arguments to the constructor call; values of primitive types are wrapped in a wrapper object of the appropriate type (e.g. a float in a Float)*

Answer (score 1):

The `args[i]` may not be casted to the desired type.

Like if you have list `"foo"` and `type[i].cast()` is expecting `int`